# Kiel traduki 'slot' esperante?

Tags: translation

Mi volas trovi taŭgan tradukon de la angla vorto "slot" kun la kunteksto:
"spaco por alia uzanto aliĝi"/ "slot for other users to join".

Mi ne tro ŝatas la vorton ingon(ĉar estas objekto) aŭ fendo(ĉar estas pli taŭga por 'split/crack').

Antaŭdankon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Esperanto, oni diras '*libera loko*' aŭ simple '*loko*'.

> - Filipo: Ĉu restas **liberaj lokoj** por la ekskurso al Bruĝo?
> - LKK-ano: Bedaŭrinde, tio jam estas plena. Ĉu vi volas elekti ion alian?
> - Filipo: Kiuj ekskursoj ankoraŭ havas **liberajn lokojn**?
> - LKK-ano: Restas **lokoj** en la ekskursoj n-roj A2, A4 kaj A8.

https://lernu.net/en/kurso/nakamura/24/14

Answer (score 3):

Mi ne plene certas ĉu mi komprenas la aferon en la angla. Mankas kunteksto.

Sed, pri la ĝenerala ideo - **loko** (aŭ eventuale **vicloko**) certe estus bona solvo.

Se temas pri "time slot" (ekzemple, por programero en kongresa horaro) oni povus diri **horo** aŭ **loko**.

- Venu rapide kun via propono ĉar restas nur kelkaj liberaj lokoj en la horaro.

Answer (score 0):

While doing some translation, I'm building [a personal generic glossary](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Psychoslave/generic_glossary/eo) where I try to disambiguate some English terms with their Esperanto counterparts. For now I only list terms, definition will come later (hopefully). You might like to have a look at entries related to "slot".

For your demand, I don't see the problem with *-ing-*. I would translate your string as "*Restantaj uzantingoj*" or "*Kvanto da asigneblaj uzantingoj*", or something else in that spirit, depending on context.

Comment: Problem is that -ingo by definition is an 'object'. and slot in this case is a vacancy/place/space

Comment: Well, if you restrict "object" to "material object", that might be a problem, but "object" do have a far broader extension (and so does *objecto*). That is, from the more abstract definition, a place is an object. From the PIV *-ing-* entry, you can find this example : *tubeto, en kiun oni metas cigaron, kiam oni ĝin fumas, estas cigaringo*. Now you may prefer to use *-uj-*, do *uzantujo*, or append *-ej-* to *-ing-*, do *uzantingejo*. Finally note that here I use "uzanto" in a metonymic manner, that is, if it's a "software user slot", that's not really the user which go inside the slot.

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus *truo* aŭ *trueto*.

Mi uzas "Slot" referencante maŝinon por hazardludo. Mi ŝatas ankaŭ *vicloko* kiam ĝi referencas al loko. Logike oni povus diri *victruo* sed  mi povas pensi pri aliaj truoj por vico krom la maŝinoj ...  :)